# Is "To send a message over the communication bus" correct?

Tags: prepositions, german

I was wondering if I could use the preposition **over** in this technical context. That is, *to send a message **over** the communication bus*.

In German one can say: *Eine Botschaft **über** den Kommunikationsbus zu senden.*

One can go/cross over the bridge from a point A into a point B.
I used the same logic in the above english example. Because the message goes from point A into point B **over** communication bus (bridge).

Is my english sentence grammatically correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'Over' is used for most communication media (except for physical mail and, strangely, television). You get "over the telephone", "over the radio", "over the internet", "over the network", "over the optical link" and so on. However you also get "via", "along" , in some cases "down" and a few other terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds good to me, especially informally. It depends somewhat on the context. For example, is there a choice of routes?

**Alternatives**

"to send a message via the communication bus"

or

"to route a message via the communication bus"

Comment: Is there a choice of routes? I would say that the message is sent via a single communication bus, but its end destination can be multiple control units.

Comment: If you *route* a message, there is an implication that you are *choosing* a route, for example via a particular server. If all communications go via the bus, I would stick with "send" and "over"

Comment: Okay, thank you.